# Group dates in a List<Dictionary<string, string>>

Tags: c#

I have a function to execute sql queries that returns me

```
List<Dictionary<string, string>>
```

The first element is the field, and the second is the value.

In a specific case, this list has the following values:

```
{ datetime, '01/23/2017 01:10:30' }
{ datetime, '01/23/2017 10:00:00' }
{ datetime, '01/23/2017 11:23:15' }
{ datetime, '01/20/2017 07:13:20' }
{ datetime, '01/20/2017 08:20:11' }
{ datetime, '01/21/2017 07:28:29' }
```

I need to convert this to:

```
{ '01/23/2017', { '01/23/2017 01:10:30', ''01/23/2017 10:00:00', '01/23/2017  11:23:15' } }
{ '01/20/2017', { '01/20/2017 07:13:20', '01/20/2017 08:20:11' } }
{ '01/21/2017', { '01/21/2017 07:28:29' } }
```

How do I proceed?

Comment: the `datetime` is not relevant, correct?

Comment: Correct, it is just the name of the field returned by the query.

Comment: The response from your database seems odd... Why a list of dictionaries?

Comment: This should be `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`

Comment: Do you have any code? What ideas have you had to solve this?

Comment: @Marco answer is great, however when posting to SO you should follow these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to describe/explain what attempts you tried first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the data you've provided, here's one way to do it. Please note, that this code is written and executed in LinqPad, so `.Dump()` only works there:

```
var source = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "datetime", "01/23/2017 01:10:30") ,
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "datetime", "01/23/2017 10:00:00" ),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "datetime", "01/23/2017 11:23:15" ),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "datetime", "01/20/2017 07:13:20" ),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "datetime", "01/20/2017 08:20:11" ),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "datetime", "01/21/2017 07:28:29" )
};

var list = source.Select (s => s.Value)
    .GroupBy (s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date)
    .ToList();

list.Dump();
```

Output:

[image]